# How do I bind a DropDownList to generic list inside a FormView bound to an ObjectDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a FormView, that I use in Edit mode only, bound to an ObjectDataSource which is selecting from a custom class.  A property of that custom class is a generic list of other objects that I want to bind to a DropDownList within the formview.

Obviously this doesn't work because you cannot set DataSource declaratively:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" DataSource="theList">
```

I thought about binding the DropDownLists in the code behind inside the ObjectDataSource's Selected event, but the FormView is not bound at that point so I don't have access to the DropDownLists.

Can I get direct access to that object the ObjectDataSource selected in the DropDownList's DataBound event perhaps?  If so, how do I get at that object.

Or, is there an all around better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try DataBound of formView?

Comment: Well, no, I'm sure I can bind the DropDownList in there, or in the DropDownList's Init or DataBound event,  but can I easily access the data in the ObjectDataSource?  For example:  In the Selected events of the ObjectDataSource I can assess the data by casting the ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs param to my objects class name like: object o = (ClassName)e.ResultValue.  Is there a way to get at that in the DropDownList DataBound event?